# KQL how to search for announcements that are not expired

Tags: search, enterprise-search, managed-property, keywordquery

I'm trying to search in an announcement list. I want the search to return only items, that aren't expired (ows_Expires >= [today]). I found, that ows_Expires is mapped to a managed property called "ExpirationTime". But I don't get, how I can query this in a KQL search string ... I tried using fixed values or today keyword, always returning 0 results:

```
ExpirationTime>=today
ExpirationTime>=[today]
ExpirationTime>=2013-01-01
ExpirationTime>=01.01.2013
```

Is there a way to query for this field?

Comment: Is it the correct property? I tried it with write<02/28/2013 and this does work for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).